# Delphi take values from an SQL query

Tags: delphi

I want to retrieve text values from this query

```
FdTmp2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT PATH_FILE FROM STORAGE_DATA';
```

FdTmp2 is a TFDQuery.

I've tried to do `FdTmp2.FieldByName('PATH_FILE').AsString := TEST;`

But it tells me `Delphi exception EDatabaseError at $8DACF859`

Comment: What are you trying to implement, please? Your *query* RDBMS with `SELECT` and RDBMS is going to a cursor. If you want to *modify*, try using `INSERT` or `UPDATE`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I only want to retrieve all the columns PATH_FILE in STORAGE_DATA and takes AsString all the columns values

Comment: If you want to retrieve, you should put it as `TEST := FdTmp2.FieldByName('PATH_FILE').AsString;` here you read from cursor and assign the value to `TEST` variable

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might need to review some basic SQL language use, please don't take this the wrong way.

If you are only trying to *retrieve* the text of the `PATH_FILE` column, your attempt of
`FdTmp2.FieldByName('PATH_FILE').AsString := TEST;` is not retrieving anything at all, in fact it is trying to *assign* the value of `TEST` to the specific record `PATH_FILE` in the table you have open. To retrieve the record's value, use `TEST := FdTmp2.FieldByName('PATH_FILE').AsString;` instead.

`EDatabase` errors can be kind of generic, maybe the table isn't connected, table isn't open, isn't editable, lots of weird things I've seen.  How does a command like
`FdTmp2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM STORAGE_DATA';` work out?

`'SELECT PATH_FILE FROM STORAGE_DATA';` This command, once executed, will give you a list of all `PATH_FILE` values from the table `STORAGE_DATA`.  If your `PATH_FILE` table has 100 records, you will have 100 records of `PATH_FILE` to work with.  Loop through them if you want, or change your SQL statement to give you smaller, more concise, results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to test first if this one produces something by doing this.
`FdTmp2.Open;`
`FdTmp2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT PATH_FILE FROM STORAGE_DATA WHERE ID_GATE = '123';`
`FdTmp2.RecordCount; `
Unfortunately RecordCount is equal to 0 ... Why it doesn't count columns ?

Comment: @Marcol1no: You can't `Open` before you assign the SQL. Assigining the SQL **closes** the  active query and changes the SQL. Set the SQL.Text, and **then** open the query. As far as why RecordCount is 0, the query is closed, because you didn't open it after changing the SQL, and RecordCount counts **rows**, not **columns**. A record is a single **row** in the dataset. You might want to Google *Delphi database tutorial* to find a good lesson on using databases with Delphi.